# Can I query DynamoDB with multiple LSIs?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a class named `Person` with three LSIs: `age`, `job_title` and `years_of_experience`. Is it possible for me to query with conditions on all three LSIs at the same time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not directly via the DynamoDB API.

You would need to query them all and union the results, and you could also use a `QueryFilter` to filter on the keys of previously obtained results on each sequential call (though this will not decrease the required throughput, and you will still need to union the results if there are more than one)